# rounding to the nearest zero, bitwise

Tags: math, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I just wonder how can i round to the nearest zero bitwise? Previously, I perform the long division using a loop. However, since the number always divided by a number power by 2. I decide to use bit shifting. So, I can get result like this:

```
12/4=3
13/4=3
14/4=3
15/4=3
16/4=4
```

can I do this by performing the long division like usual?

```
12>>2
13>>2
```

if I use this kind of bit shifting, are the behavior different for different compiler? how about rounding up? I am using visual c++ 2010 compiler and gcc. thx

Comment: I think it depends on a few factors, are you shifting signed or unsigned ints? What width? I found this link interesting for learning more about C and integers http://blog.regehr.org/archives/721

Comment: ah. it's signed int (32bit)

Comment: In my experience if you write `int x; int y; y = x/4;` then any compiler worth a damn should convert that `/4` into a bitshift for you (with optimisations turned on).

Comment: Why is `floating-point` involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitwise shifts are equivalent to round-to-negative-infinity divisions by powers of two, meaning that the answer is never bigger than the unrounded value (so e.g. (-3) >> 1 is equal to -2).

For non-negative integers, this is equivalent to round-to-zero.

Comment: what do you mean by round to negative infinity? so, you are saying, the behavior produced by bitwise shifts isn't vary from one compiler to different compiler?

Comment: Provided you're using 2s-complement and arithmetic shifting for signed ints, it should be the same for all compilers.

Comment: Round to negative infinity means if the result is say 2.5 or -2.5, the rounding always makes the number smaller (to the next smaller integer), so 2.x => 2 and -2.x => -3.

Comment: Hi @nneonneo ...can you offer a source or spec sheet somewhere so I can read more about this? I'm getting into JS and using bitwise operators, and I'm trying to wrap my head around exactly *how* a bitwise operator will always truncate numbers after a decimal point. Yours is the first answer I've found that offers an explanation, and I'd like to know where this knowledge came from.